# Integrated Circuit Chip number AUT1020218-A. Does anyone know what this is or where to get one?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

A chip number in this device is AUT1020218-A. Does anyone know what it is? I am trying to repair a timer device.[image]

Comment: Howard Ostfeld - Hi, FYI these are the current "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you can supply from that list, the better the chances of identification. Thanks. (Please [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/541243/edit) your question to add details, don't write them as comments below. More rules and information about how Stack Exchange sites are different from typical internet forums, are in the [help] and [tour].)

Comment: Is it possible to share a photo of the chip? My quick search didn't give any results. How many pins does the chip have? is it SMD or THT? An image would be really helpful.

Comment: Hello GNA, Trying to post photos but not easy for me using this website. Can I email it to you? Thanks

Comment: It is a 18 pin THT IC

Comment: @HowardOstfeld you can't post photos here in the comments. You need to edit your question and add them up there.

Comment: Thank You BRHANS! I had to crop my original photo to meet the 2MB max. Why is the max so low?